# What does it mean for a quantity to be immaterial and why can we replace it by its tensor product?

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

[image]

So if we have a composite material that has only one type of fiber that has a specified direction expressed with the vector ***a***, then why can we replace the diretion vector ***a*** by its tensor product when we want to express it in the strain energy function? And what do we mean that its immaterial? Thanks

[Source of the picture](https://web.mit.edu/abeyaratne/Volumes/RCA_Vol_II.pdf)  (MIT university)

Answer (score 1):

> And what do we mean that it is immaterial?

Presumably you are referring to the following text in your extract:

> Since the sense of the vector **$a$** is immaterial ...

Here, the word 'immaterial' means irrelevant. Thus they are saying the sense of the vector **$a$** is irrelevant for their purposes. This is why they go on to say:

> changing **$a\rightarrow -a$** does not change the energy ...

Now, this transformation changes the sense of the vector, but as it doesn't change the energy, the sense of the vector is irrelevant to the energy.

Comment: Thanks, but what about about the tensor product? Why does being immaterial implies the replacement with the tensor product?

Comment: @user134613: It doesn't imply anything the sort. Perhaps you should look up the meaning of 'immaterial' in a dictionary as see whether that helps you find your bearings or not.